# presentModalViewController: doesn't return

Tags: uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a really weird thing happening.  In my app delegate, I'm calling presentModalViewController: on a UITabBarController to display a custom class (LoadingViewController) that implements loadView to display an image.  When I test this in the simulator against an iOS 4.x device (iPhone or iPad), it works fine at all orientations.  However, when I test against a 3.2 iPad, it only works fine if the orientation is portrait.  If it is landscape, the presentModalViewController: method doesn't return.  The loadView and viewDidLoad methods get called but the viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods don't get called.

Any ideas?

Here's the code for loadView in LoadingViewController:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    CGRect mainScreenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    UIImageView * loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: mainScreenBounds];

    loadingImageView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    loadingImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    NSString * splashImageName = [self getSplashImageName: [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
    loadingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: splashImageName];

    UIActivityIndicatorView * spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    CGRect spinnerFrame = spinner.frame;

    spinnerFrame.origin.x = (mainScreenBounds.size.width - spinnerFrame.size.width) / 2;
    spinnerFrame.origin.y = mainScreenBounds.size.height * 0.7f;

    spinner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
                             | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
                             | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
                             | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    spinner.frame = spinnerFrame;
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    [spinner startAnimating];

    [loadingImageView addSubview: spinner];

    // Add a label indicating we are working so the user knows what we are doing.
    UIColor * textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CGRect labelFrame = loadingImageView.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = 40;
    labelFrame.origin.y = spinnerFrame.origin.y - 100;
    UILabel * workingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
    workingLabel.font             = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 18.0];
    workingLabel.textColor        = textColor;
    workingLabel.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
    workingLabel.textAlignment    = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    workingLabel.text             = NSLocalizedString(@"Searching for location...", @"Searching for location...");
    workingLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
                                  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
                                  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
                                  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
                                  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                                  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [loadingImageView addSubview: workingLabel];
    [workingLabel release];

    [spinner release];

    self.view = loadingImageView;
    [loadingImageView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we ended up with is to not use presentModalViewController at all but to set the LoadingViewController as the root view controller.  Obviously this isn't a complete solution, but fortunately it was good enough for us.  What's frustrating is not knowing why presentModalViewController doesn't work now when it worked fine in the previous version of our app.  There's something we've done that has broken it.

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController should be the RootViewController when using `presentModalViewController.` Also there is an issue with IOS 3.2 that when using `presentModalViewController` in landscape with the UITabBarController if all it's viewcontrollers don't override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and return yes for landscape, it will cause `presentModalViewController` to hang.